# How to configure Roll-up Babel's plugin

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs, rollup

I have created a rollup project. I wasn't able to use `rollup -c && rollup -c --environment PRODUCTION` without using less than two files :

- [rollup.config.js](https://github.com/kopax/rollup-umd/blob/master/rollup.config.js#L55)
- [.babelrc](https://github.com/kopax/rollup-umd/blob/master/.babelrc)

Some people told me on freenode I should only have one file.

I wan't to be able to run the following code with rollup:

**src/index.js**

```
export default true;
```

**src/tests/index.test.js**

```
import demo from '../index';

describe('demo test', () => {
  it('should return true', () => {
    expect(demo).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

I couldn't find any logical explanation on what plugin should be in what file, all I know is I wasn't able to make it work with only one configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `rollup-plugin-babel` you can specify `babelrc: false` to tell it to ignore your `.babelrc` file, then specify the `plugins` and `presets` parameters in your `rollup.config.js`.

If you included the code for your `rollup.config.js` and `.babelrc` files, I could be more specific.